# How to go back to a previous viewpager fragment from an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I know there are similar questions to the one I'm asking but none of them was able to solve the issue I'm having.

I Have a bottom navigation view with five fragments that use viewpager, one of these fragments opens an activity.

**Problem**

When I open the activity from the fragment it works fine but the issue is the when I press back it goes back to the same fragment that opens the activity.

**Solution**

I want when I press back out of the activity that it goes to a previous fragment apart from the fragment that calls the activity.

For example: if the user is on HomeFragment and the user clicks the fragment that opens the activity(NewsFragment), and the user press back they Should go back to HomeFragment, not NewsFragment.

**What I tried so far:**

MainActivity for the BottomnNvigationView and it's On Back Press

```
 private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_library:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        temp = temp.replace("-0", "") + "-0";
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_technology:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        temp = temp.replace("-1", "") + "-1";
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                        temp = temp.replace("-2", "") + "-2";
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_science:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                        temp = temp.replace("-3", "") + "-3";
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_news:
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
                        temp = temp.replace("-4", "") + "-4";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BrowserActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else {
        String[] words = temp.split("-");
        if(words.length<=2)
            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 2) {
                temp = "";
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            }else
                finish();
        else {
            temp = temp.replace("-" + words[words.length - 1], "");
            int pos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == pos)
                pos = 2;
            else
                pos = 1;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.parseInt(words[words.length - pos]));
        }
    }


}
```

The Activity that is call from the fragment (BrowersActivity) On Back Press

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1,false);
    }else{
        finish();
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest solution would be to finish the first activity after starting the second one so:

```
               case R.id.nav_news:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
                    temp = temp.replace("-4", "") + "-4";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BrowserActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish()
                    return true;
```

And in the second activity in onBackPressed, restart the first activity

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. While your code does work in the sense of not going back to the news fragment, what I'm really looking for is to go back to the fragment that was called before I clicked the news fragment to open the second activity, not go back to the main fragment all the time like in this code.